# Flutter TextField label is outside of background when focused

Tags: flutter

Title should say everything. Nevertheless, here are some pictures for better understanding.

How it should look like (Google Material Components):
[image]

How it actually looks like:
[image]

But please ignore the bottom border of the pic "how it should look like". The problem is just that the label is outside of the background.

And also the Text and LabelText is not vertically centered. Another picture:
[image]

I also tried playing around with the paddings (top and bottom) but either it didn't change anything or I got an error.

And here is the source code:

```
return TextField(
  onChanged: (String? value) {
    print(value);
    onChanged(value);
  },
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
    labelText: labelText,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      color: kInputColor,
      fontSize: 14.0,
    ),
    filled: true,
    fillColor: kInputFillColor,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
      top: 14.0,
      bottom: 14.0,
      left: 14.0,
      right: 14.0,
    ),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
    ),
  ),
  cursorWidth: 1.5,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 14.0,
  ),
);
```

Comment: If your goal is the first image then you need to use an `UnderlineInputBorder` instead of `OutlineInputBorder`

Comment: @PatrickMahomes no I would like to have the same border that i am using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the type of border I used. Through the answer of @Diwyansh, I found out that the default border a `TextField` uses is the `UnderlineInputBorder`. I found out that this type of border also has the properties to set `borderRadius` and `borderSide`. So when I use `UnderlineInputBorder` instead of `OutlineInputBorder` (which for me sounded more meaningful than `UnderlineInputBorder`), the label is drawn within the background of the `TextField`. This is how my source code looks now:

```
return TextField(
  onChanged: (String? value) {
    print(value);
    onChanged(value);
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
    labelText: labelText,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      color: kInputColor,
      fontSize: 14.0,
    ),
    filled: true,
    fillColor: kInputFillColor,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
      top: 14.0,
      bottom: 12.0,
      left: 14.0,
      right: 14.0,
    ),
    border: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
    ),
  ),
  cursorWidth: 1.5,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 14.0,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it InputDecoration Property

```
TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Label",
        filled: true),
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, so basically the problem is the border i am using?

Comment: OutlinedBorder cover all the edges and this is an defaut nature of the textfield.

mark as answer and upvote too if it solved your issue. Thanks

Comment: I am gonna try it now.

Comment: Okay so you didn't exactly solved the problem, but your suggestions/answer helped me finding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**According to The Official Flutter Documentation of OutlineInputBorder** https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlineInputBorder/OutlineInputBorder.html

InputDecoration.floatingLabelBehavior, which should be set to FloatingLabelBehavior.never when the borderSide is BorderSide.none. If let as FloatingLabelBehavior.auto, the label will extend beyond the container as if the border were still being drawn.

Which means if `BorderSide` is set to `BorderSide.none`, just like you did, the label would look outside the background container when focused.

so you just need to set `floatingLabelBehavior` to `FloatingLabelBehavior.never`.
which would make it work like `hintText`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I want the label to float to the top and not just look like a hint text.